# Could not format log-string

Tags: windows-xp, net-snmp, snmptrapd

while recieving snmptrap on linux system...every thing working fine,but in windows server & XP I am getting `Could not format log-string`.Anyone please help me to solve this problem.
  I am using Net-SNMP-5.6.1.1 for windows server.
   Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of supplied  `snprintf()` is used instead of `sprintf()` as it does limit checks 
for string length. or because of `Void debugmsg_hex(const char *token, const u_char * thedata, size_t len)` which can accept no longer than `LOGLENGTH==1024`. 
Resolve: 
verify `snmp_logging.c` and remove checks.
[CODE](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/snmp__logging_8c_source.html)

---

what is complete error message. I need the printed code.

Comment: Hi Grijesh ,I am actually viewing this message in Event-Viewer,& its only showing "Could not format log-string"..

Comment: In `logging.c` there is a macro `LOGLENGTH` increase it size , recompile and run ..otherwise disable debug mode.

Comment: Try with this option `snmptrab -Dmib_init -H ..`

Comment: Hi Grijesh,sorry for being late...I will do it..anyways, Thankyou very much for your kindly effort.will you please check out this link ..http://serverfault.com/questions/458338/server-ip-address-is-not-getting-displayed-in-snmp-trap-messages   .I am desperately looking around for its answer but don't getting...Will you be please help me out to solve this problem, looking for your kindly help

Comment: sorry I have no idea on this ...I can give an e-mail-id where you can ask this issue.

Comment: k...It would be appreciating if u can provide it..looking forward to it.

Comment: Here I used to ask my queries and got response too. `net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net,
 Niels Baggesen <nba@users.sourceforge.net>`

Comment: Hi Grijesh!! Would you please tell me about the location of {snmp_logging.c } .I searched a lot but didn't find it out .Thank you

Comment: @Gaurav Hi Gaurav, the file path is `/net-snmp-5.7.1/snmplib/snmp_logging.c`

Comment: but I have download 5.6.1.1 version of net-snmp(binary file) .& it does not contain any snmplib folder

Comment: At the time of installation,I got only /usr folder.

Comment: Oh! really?...be sure that you have not made any mistake. are you in Linux or windows?

Comment: yes ......Windows Server 2008 Machine.On Linux its working fine ,means I am getting the traps perfectly(on Linux I am using 5.5 version)

Comment: What I am thinking is, that you are talking about Source files,while I am using .exe(binary file) of 6.1.1 version of Net-Snmp for installation .What would I have to do now??

Comment: And have you done the Net-Snmp Installation by compiling the source folder (not through Binary File) ? If Yes..then please give me some hint.Because I don't have any idea

Comment: Yes I am commenting about source files. You can download source file and compile them manually. I think.,Specially If you want to develop over net-snmp.

Comment: Yes I compiled first then installed myself explicitly. There is a README file. steps are clearly written in which. first run `./configure` then `make`.

Comment: Get instructions from [**web-page**](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/INSTALL.html) also.

Comment: Ok then ..THANK YOU,Once Again

Comment: Yes off-course ...we have to remove. otherwise how would you update?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21742/discussion-between-gaurav-and-grijesh-chauhan)